# Linq statement crashing (no exception) on 2nd method call instantiate object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which instantiates an object, some of the properties of this object are arrays where i use linq to fetch the data.

```
private static GrowthYieldStructure CreateGrowthYieldStructure(int timberType, IEnumerable<Tree> trees)
    {
        var trees1 = trees;

        return new GrowthYieldStructure
                   {
                       TimberType = timberType,

                       CurrentDbhList = trees1.Select(x => x.DBH).ToArray(),
                       CurrentSpeciesList = trees1.Select(x => x.SpeciesNumber).ToArray(),
                       CurrentTpaList = trees1.Select(x => x.TPA).ToArray(),
                       CurrentTreeListLength = trees1.Count()

                   };
    }
```

The first time I call this method it works fine.
The second time it will fail with no exception on the second select statement.

-no matter which value its attempting to select

For instance, `trees1.Select(x => x.DBH).ToArray()` works, `trees1.Select(x => x.SpeciesNumber).ToArray()` crashes.

(I've tried switching the fetching order / making local variable copies / I've checked that values exist and they do, nothing out of the ordinary / using try/catch (no exp caught))

Edit:
I made more local variables to store the IEnumerable; still fails

If I only have one select statement it will run fine...

--
Edit2: (calling code - could be off going from memory)
stands,plots,trees are all IEnumerable (T being Stand,Plot,Tree)

```
foreach (var plot in plots.Where(x => x.StandID.Equals(stands.ID))) { 
  var plot1 = plot;
  var treeList = trees.Where(x => x.PlotID.Equals(plot1.ID)); 
  var growthYieldStructure = CreateGrowthYieldStructure(stands.TimberType, treeList); }
```

Edit3:
Finally saw this error: 
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Then finally realized my error-

It was actually the code using after the object creation.
I was using arrays to send to a external library since arrays are reference types this worked out they way I suspected.
But since I was not copying the arrays and instead creating a new local variable which would have the same memory reference.

### This caused the next object init to fail since it wanted to write in the same memory loc..

I just changed the object to use IEnumerable this way i can have the array reference once.
Sorry for the confusion.

Any thoughts to why it is crashing?

Comment: You say it fails with no exception - could you more precisely describe the nature of the failure?

Comment: If the `ToList` attempt didn't work, then maybe the property getters for `Tree` are failing.  Also, maybe the code that creates `IEnumerable<Tree>` generates null references.  You should post the code for both.

Comment: What part of that line does it crash on? the `.Select()`?  the `.ToArray()`?  Is one of the `Tree` objects null?  Turn on exceptions (in VS, Debug->Exceptions..., check all).

Comment: whats odd is the first time I call this method it works - all properties are set

Comment: the crash causes no exception, just silently exits

Comment: the exception is probably getting caught and handled somewhere else...for debugging purposes can you wrap the calling code in try...catch and then breakpoint in the catch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be do to the `IEnumerable` being an `IQueryable` and it is trying to enumerate more than once.

Try changing the line:

```
var trees1 = trees;
```

to

```
var trees1 = trees.ToList();
```

that will force the enumeration and `trees1` will be a `List` instead of the possible `IQueryable`

Comment: Well the thing to consider with my suggestion is the parameter `trees` being passed to the method. If the *same* reference is used during all subsequent calls then the `ToList()` will itself be an additional enumeration and cause the issue rather then resolve. Can you post the calling code for `CreateGrowthYieldStructure` particularly concerning the `trees` parameter?

Comment: the issue all along was an external call to a library which corrupted memory... so on the next iteration for that memory reference caused a read error.